# How to fix "WARNING: not a detached signature"?

Tags: gnupg

I am trying to sign a Python file using the following:

```
gpg --sign --output ./ulagen.py.sig ./ulagen.py
```

When I verify the signature using `gpg --verify ./ulagen.py.sig`, I get the following error:

```
gpg: WARNING: not a detached signature; file 'ulagen.py' was NOT verified!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Problem solved using `gpg --detach-sig --output ./ulagen.py.sig ./ulagen.py`, but still trying to figure out `--detach-sig`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a detached signature you need to use:

```
gpg --detach-sig --sign --output ./ulagen.py.sig ./ulagen.py
```

But what is a detached signature?
By default, GPG creates a **signed copy** of a file.
So if you use

```
gpg --sign --output ./ulagen.py.sig ./ulagen.py
```

The file `ulagen.py.sig` will contain a **compressed copy** of `ulagen.py` and its **signature**.

You can use the command

```
gpg --output ./ulagen-restored.py --decrypt ./ulagen.py.sig
```

This will extract the file contained in `ulagen.py.sig` and save it as `ulagen-restored.py`

Just verifying the file using

```
gpg --verify ./ulagen.py.sig
```

will verify, that the signature matches the file **contained in** `ulagen.py.sig`.
It is in no way related to the file `ulagen.py`, and that's what GPG is telling you.

A detached signature is just the signature **without a copy** of the file. To verify it, you need the file separately.

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to include both `--detach-sig` and `--sign` or is `--sign` implicit?

Comment: `--detach-sig` should be enough

Answer (score 1):

I actually like to create a detached signature via a plain ASCII output. That is possible by using the `--armor` option. The default GPG will generate otherwise a binary output (sig file).

To create such a neat detached signature (asc):

```
gpg --detach-sig --armor <file>
```